# Удаление столбца по условию numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Всем привет, я хочу удалить столбец в матрице nxm через условие, но есть проблемы с реализацией. думал, что таким образом сработает, но интерпритатор выдает ошибку:

```
a = a[a[:,[0,m-1]]%5 == 0]
```

можете подсказать, как решить эту проблему?
По заданию, необходимо найти элемент, кратный 5 и удалить столбец с ним

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалить все столбцы, в которых есть числа кратные 5:

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.arange(24).reshape(3,8)
```

Имеем массив:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
 [16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23]]
```

Удаляем по заданному условию:

```
np.delete(arr,np.where(arr%5 == 0)[1],1)
```

Результат:

```
[[ 1  3  6]
 [ 9 11 14]
 [17 19 22]]
```

А вообще-то это описано в любой статье (не говоря уже о книге), где рассказывается о numpy.  Рекомендую с этого и начинать.